# curl php json always return a wrong response

Tags: php, json, curl

I need your help to check whats wrong with my code.
I had tried to post a json data from postman and it returnen a correct response.
But the following code always returns a wrong response.

```
<?php
$data_login = array('email'=>'dada@dada.com','password'=>'hahaha','confirmation_password'=>'hahaha');

$api_data = json_encode($data_login);
$api_url = 'http://dev.badr.co.id/freedom/auth/register';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

wrong response :

```
{"success":false,"message":"1000: Not a valid request"}
```

correct response :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "user registration success",
    "data": null
}
```

This return a correct response if i post the data using postman :

[correct_response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jxUb.png)

Comment: Without the details of the API - what the endpoint expects - I doubt whether we'll be much help.

Comment: It says:- `{"success":false,"message":"1000: Not a valid request"}` that means you are not using `API` in it's told way

Comment: I ran the CLI curl example in the api documentation and got the same response: `{"success":false,"message":"1000: Not a valid request"}`.  I have no idea if this is a working endpoint or not.  I can't even work out what Postman or Freedom Php is, from leafing through the website.

Comment: @kartaterazu can you be a little more explicit, when you say it returns false?  Can you `var_dump($result)` please.

Comment: @Progrock this is the result {"success":false,"message":"1000: Not a valid request"}

Comment: @kartaterazu edit your question to reflect that please.  Otherwise people think you are getting a 'false' result from curl_exec.

Comment: This is a correct response when i try post the data using postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jxUb.png

Comment: @Progrock follow this link to know about postman https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If `curl_exec()` is returning `false` that means that the request is failing somehow.

You can work out how by using the [`curl_error()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). Call it in between `curl_exec()` and `curl_close()` and it will return a string with information on what went wrong with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return values of the initializing and executing cURL functions. [curl_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [curl_errno()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) will contain further information in case of failure:

```
try {
    $data_login = array('email'=>'dada@dada.com','password'=>'hahaha','confirmation_password'=>'hahaha');
    $api_data = json_encode($data_login);
    $api_url = 'http://dev.badr.co.id/freedom/auth/register';

    $ch = curl_init();

    if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (FALSE === $result)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
} catch(Exception $e) {

    echo sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: @krishnaraj, rather than proxying the exception through trigger_error, why not just output the curl_error for this demo/example?  Though having tested the code, the code doesn't error for me.  I get a JSON response.

Comment: @kartaterazu Display errors could be turned off in the php.ini or your Apache config file.  You can turn it on in the script:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
You should see the same messages in the PHP error log.